# How to save view in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a SPA with angularjs. If there are two pages in the application let it be A and B. Currently I'm at page A and I've done some operations on the page(like filtering, search etc.), then I have navigate to page B and again came back to page A. But all the operations done on page A should persist when I came back(all the filter,search operations should persist. How its possible) ?

Comment: Depends on what "other page" means. Please provide a lot more specific details. See [ask] ... and ... [mcve]

Comment: define "operations done"... are you talking about fetching the data that is presented on that view?  Are you talking about saving UX state like checkboxes or selections?  This is a really too broad of a question for anyone to answer in its current state

Comment: i guess you could save the scope data in localstorage and when that page is loaded check that value is in localstorage and load it to the scope.

Comment: Maybe [cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) is what you are looking for

Comment: I have edited the question with a better description.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you can do is save all the values you need to create that state in a route param like so:

```
  .state(state1, { 
     url: '/state1', 
     params: {'paramters': null}, 
     controller: 'controller', 
   })
```

You can then use it in your controller to restore your view to whatever it was at from before like this: `$stateParams.paramters`

To save the 'current view' you can also tell Angular to not cache your view by default:

```
      .state(state1, { 
         url: '/state1', 
         params: {'paramters': null}, 
         cache: false,
         controller: 'controller', 
       })
```

This will make Angular re-run your controller code everytime.

I hope this is of use.

Comment: should mention that answer assumes op is using ui-router. Note that caching won't store model state

Comment: This is true.  But the concept is the same

Comment: Not only values, but I want exactly the same page with all the previous operations.

Comment: @AgilC you need to store your model that drives that view... but until you provide more specifics where and how is yet to be determined

Comment: @charlietfl: "you need to store your model that drives that view." - This is what I exactly need to know. How can we store a model in angular js?? Can we use a localstorage for this purpose ?

Comment: @AgilC yes. Use a service also and can really make it simple using [`ngStorage`](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) module which handles all the getting and setting

Comment: @charlietfl how can we store the current view in a variable so that we can store it in localstorage. So that i can recreate the exact page after some navigation to other pages.

Comment: You need to store the model that view uses to do rendering